# How does GitLab CI of GitLab.com know where to find a registered local runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a test pipeline on Gitlab.com with my personal user account. I created a local gitlab runner container and have registered it with tags for that project. It runs normally and I need to understand a specific point here. How does Gitlab CI on the internet know how to reach the runner on my laptop? It detects a public ip address which belongs to the place where I am doing this test, while I am setting behind a router which does natting and give me a private ip address. Further more, the runner runs inside a docker container. 
How is this working exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your local runner that connects to GitLab, not the other way around. You can connect to GitLab through your browser and with git. It the same way, `gitlab-runner` uses a web API to check for jobs a few times a second. This makes it so that no special configuration is necessary to get a `gitlab-runner` up and running, as access to webpages (port 80) is open on almost all devices.

Here is a little more information that I found:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1230